# How to change the iteration of stack in C++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to delete the last N-1 elements of a stack but instead the first N-1 are deleted.

This is the output of the program:

```
1. 8
2. 10
3. 4
4. 9
5. 1
6. 3
7. 5
8. 9
9. 4
10. 10
```

If we choose the key "5" with value 1, all elements after it should be removed from the stack but instead all previous elements are deleted.

The process of deleting the elements is located in the function `find_enth_from_bottom();`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>
using namespace std;

stack <int> stek;

void change_enth_from_bottom(stack <int>& smack, int en, int newvalue);
int find_enth_from_bottom(stack <int>& smack, int en);

int find_enth_from_bottom(stack <int>& smack, int en) {
    long size = smack.size();

    if (size < en) {
         return -1;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < size - en; i++) {
        smack.pop();
    }

    return smack.top();
}

void change_enth_from_bottom(stack <int>& smack, int en, int newvalue) {
    find_enth_from_bottom(smack, en);
    smack.pop();
    smack.push(newvalue);
}

int main() {
    int position, value, counter = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
        int k_val = rand() % 10 + 1;
        cout << i << ". " << k_val << endl;
        stek.push(k_val);
    }

    cout << "Enter position: "; cin >> position;
    cout << endl << "Enter new value: "; cin >> value;

    change_enth_from_bottom(stek, position, value);
    cout << "The value of the element with position " << position << " is now changed to " << find_enth_from_bottom(stek, position) << endl;

    cout << "New stack interface" << endl;

    while(!stek.empty()) {
        counter++;
        int a = stek.top();
        stek.pop();
        cout << counter << ". " << a << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You do know `stack` is LIFO right?

Comment: If the stack has n elements, and you want to delete n-1 elements, pop the top one element and save it, clear the stack, push the one element onto the empty stack.  Done.

Comment: I find it funny that you use `using namespace std;` then have to resort to bogus names such as `stek` or `smack` tu avoid name collisions. If only there was a way to isolate all these pesky standard names into a separate space :)

Comment: You should never need to do this with a stack. At any time when using a stack, you should only care about the element at the top of the stack, that is, the element in the stack that was added most recently. If you find yourself needing access to the elements further down the stack, then a stack is not the data structure you should use.

Comment: You can use e.g. a `std::vector` like a `std::stack` (by `std::vector::push_back()` and `std::vector::pop_back()`) but `std::vector` provides more member functions to insert or delete at any position.

Comment: I know but my homework is to use stack for this operation and i am stuck here.

Comment: @Eljay gave you a simple algorithm.

Comment: @MikeBorkland I need to keep all elements from the bottom not to keep only 1.

Comment: Unlike almost all other classes in `std`, there is a defined member object in `std::stack`, the `protected: Container c;`

Comment: Are you wanting to add the elements back in again? The names of your functions suggest so, but the implementation doesn't

Answer (score 0):

You can get at the underlying container, and do whatever you want to it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>

using container_t = std::stack<int>::container_type;

namespace detail
{
    class stack_access : std::stack<int>
    {
    public:
        using stack::c;
    };
}

constexpr container_t std::stack<int>::* container_ptr = &detail::stack_access::c;

int find_enth_from_bottom(std::stack<int> & stack, int en) {
    return (stack.*container_ptr)[stack.size() - en];
}

void change_enth_from_bottom(std::stack<int> & stack, int en, int newvalue) {
    (stack.*container_ptr)[stack.size() - en] = newvalue;
}

int main() {
    using std::cin;
    using std::cout;
    using std::endl;

    std::stack<int> stack;

    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
        int k_val = rand() % 10 + 1;
        cout << i << ". " << k_val << endl;
        stack.push(k_val);
    }

    int position, value, counter = 0;

    cout << "Enter position: "; cin >> position;
    cout << endl << "Enter new value: "; cin >> value;

    change_enth_from_bottom(stack, position, value);
    cout << "The value of the element with position " << position << " is now changed to " << find_enth_from_bottom(stack, position) << endl;

    cout << "New stack interface" << endl;

    while(!stack.empty()) {
        counter++;
        int a = stack.top();
        stack.pop();
        cout << counter << ". " << a << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

[See it live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/27e3ec1207815fcb)